# PapaParse: Why does the [data] array within the step: function only contain one element?

Tags: typescript, database, mongodb, parsing, papaparse

I am attempting to parse a CSV, and ideally load it directly into a mongo database during the process. Papaparse has a `step:` function which allows me to stream in my large csv file and log the results one row at a time. I'd like to access the elements of the row (there are 8, all strings) so I can assign them as specific values in my db schema. However, when I attempt to access these indexes, Typescript tells me that the data array (`row.data`) has only one element!

This is bizarre to me because `console.log(row.data)` during the parse will show the arrays I want to access, containing the 8 elements per row.

```
parse(file, {
    download: false,
    step: function(row) {
        console.log("Row: at index 0", row.data); // successfully logs array with 8 elements for each row
    console.log(row.data[0]) // lint tells me that row.data only contains a single element
    },
    complete: function() {
        console.log("All done!");
    }
});
```

I'd like to avoid transferring the results to an interim object if I can, and just parse directly into my database. I'd appreciate any guidance on making this process work with the current set up, or some alternative approach that could achieve a similar result.

Thank you!!

Comment: _"Parsing huge text files is facilitated by streaming, where the file is loaded a little bit at a time, parsed, and the results are sent to your `step` callback function, **row-by-row**. You can also get results chunk-by-chunk (which is usually faster) by using the chunk callback function in the same way."_ ([Source](https://www.papaparse.com/faq#streaming)) - Working as intended...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `@types/papaparse` then the parse method expects a type parameter. In your example you seem to be expecting an array of strings, since you didn't configure PapaParse to look for headers.

You should be able to resolve your error by specifying a `string[]` data type:

```ts
parse<string[]>(file, {
    step: function(row) {
        console.log(row.data[0])
    }
}
```

However, if your CSVs have a header row, you might have an easier time working with the data by using a structured data type:

```csv
id,email,name
1000,ada@example.com,Ada
1001,bob@example.com,Bob
```

```ts
interface UserRow {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    email: string;
}

parse<UserRow>(file, {
    headers: true,
    step: function(row) {
        console.log(row.data.name)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Steve B!! This is my first project with Typescript. This was super helpful and fixed my error :)